# Drupal Live Search Results

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-search

[Drupal Search Modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPRZF.jpg)
I'm new to working with Drupal and I'm trying to rework the search functionality on a website.  It currently has the user enter the term and hit enter to conduct the search. The client would like it to be an autocomplete ajax type of search page where after the user has entered like 3 characters it would start to display results that match.

There doesn't seem to be much documentation out there for this stuff, at least that I could find.  I've included an image of the search modules that are installed on the website.  I've went through and enabled most of them but still nothing.

Is there a different module that you recommend to use?  Or is there a way to just do Drupal Ajax Search without using a module?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @a-mikhailov  I was trying to avoid modules if possible but I did end up enabling that module plus a couple others.  It isn't exactly what the client wants yet but there is a glimmer of hope at least that we can get it 90% there and they will be satisfied for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this [Search Autocomplete](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_autocomplete) module?